# How to modify write permission on current buffer in emacs?

Tags: permissions, emacs

Is it possible to change the write permissions on a file from inside emacs, without killing/re-opening the buffer?

Sometimes I forget to modify the permissions on a file before opening it. I can modify the permissions from inside emacs (`M-! chmod u+w filename`) but this doesn't update the buffer which remains write protected and refuses to modify the file.

Is there a way to update permissions inside the buffer? Bonus point if I can assign this to a shortcut!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After changing the file mode, and before doing any edit, run `M-x revert-buffer` to reload the file. If the file is now writable, the buffer will no longer be read-only.

Alternatively, type `C-x C-q` (`read-only-mode`). This makes the buffer no longer read-only. You can edit and even save, but you'll get a confirmation prompt asking whether you want to overwrite the read-only file.

Comment: While C-x C-q still works, as of emacs 24.3 it now calls read-only-mode rather than toggle-read-only and toggle-read-only has been disabled.

Answer (score 13):

To change the read-only status of a buffer, use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> (toggle `read-only-mode`). To change file permissions, you can run `dired` on the file's directory (<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>), search for the file by <kbd>C-s</kbd> and use <kbd>M</kbd> to change its mode.

Comment: Apparently, you've missed `dired-jump` (normally bound to `C-x C-j`).  It runs `dired` and jumps to the line for the file you're editing.

Comment: @cjm: It does not work for me unless I load `dired-x`.

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten that I'd set up an autoload for `dired-jump` about 20 years ago.  I recommend it.

Comment: Annoyingly `toggle-read-only` has been replaced with `read-only-mode`, although the binding is the same.

Answer (score 3):

If the workflow requires to change the file permission of the buffer repeatedly, then having a custom function would help like the following.

This works only on unix machines(executes system command "chmod"

```
(defun chmod-plus-w ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-to-string (concat "chmod +w " (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))))
  (revert-buffer))
```